# Где хранится значение примитивного поля в классе-обертке?

Tags: java, стек, heap

Где хранится значение примитивного поля в классе-обертке в языке Java? В куче или стеке?

Answer (score 3):

Если отбросить нюансы, типа скаляризации, то память под все объекты выделяется в куче, в том числе под обёртки. Соответственно и поля этих объектов тоже находятся в куче, независимо от того, примитивного ли они типа или ссылочного.